# Flagging An Answer in Review Queue - then what?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, flags, not-an-answer

I can't seem to find the best approach or documentation on how to handle a particular issue.  So you go to *Review* and someone clearly post this:

> ```
>        You should always provide code when asking a question.
> ```

Now granted they didn't have the required reputation to post a *Comment*.  But it still isn't a valid answer.  So I *Flagged* for a Moderator.  As I can't move it to a comment.  But after I've done my needed editing.

In those type of instances, do you just go:

- No Action Needed.
- Skip

I usually skip, but I'm not really sure if I should be.

What is the best approach for those instances?

---

**Update:**

I'm mostly asking cause for the *First Time* when I Flagged the question, the I'm done actually became **Grey** instead of allowing me to select it.

Comment: Doesn't flagging enable "I'm done"?

Comment: Once you've completed actions inside review, you click the **I'm Done** button to complete review. Are you leaving the review panel to edit and flag or something?

Comment: @DanielFischer It actually didn't enable it, it turned grey on me.

Comment: "the I'm done actually _became_ Grey" Wait, it's greyed out initially. If its colour changes, that should mean it becomes enabled.

Comment: @DanielFischer It started off black; then when I flagged it, it turned grey.  So I had "No Action" or "Skip" and was like "uh?"

Comment: Erm, yes, right, "Uh?" If it started off black something was amiss already.

Comment: Could be related to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174975/all-four-buttons-disabled-after-closing-recommend-deletion-dialog)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes, they should be flagged because they aren't valid answer.

> Now granted they didn't have the required reputation to post a
>   Comment.

Well, reputation unlocks privileges. If you don't have enough to perform a certain task, than don't do it. Posting an answer instead of a comment is wrong, not a solution.

> the First Time when I Flagged the question, the I'm done actually
>   became Grey instead of allowing me to select it.

I think this should not happen.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, yeah I actually had some Moderators decline those on Flags on me.  But that is good to know.