# All four buttons disabled after closing Recommend Deletion dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

I found a problem when reviewing Low Quality Posts. If I click on <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> dialog is opened. When I click somewhere on a page, outside of dialog, it is closed, but all four buttons <kbd>Looks Good</kbd>, <kbd>Edit</kbd>, <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd> are disabled and can't be clicked. I'm using newest Firefox 19.0.2.

If dialog is closed with <kbd>X</kbd> everything works fine.

Screenshots:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed and will be out in the next deployment.